# about Schedulers.newThread()

Tags: rx-java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
    Observable.from(list)
            .map(new Func1<Integer, String>() {
                @Override
                public String call(Integer integer) {
                    return   String.format("%d ",integer);
                }
            }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .subscribe(new Action1<String>() {
                @Override
                public void call(String s) {
                    System.out.print(s);
                }
            });
}
```

Here's a test when i use rxjava. it print nothing.i don't know why.Anybody can give me a help? thanks.

Comment: your main method returns before observer code is executed. To fix that, you can add .toBlocking() before .subscribe(Action1)

Comment: thanks a lot i got the reason of my problem(the main method has finished)

Answer (score 3):

RxJava standard schedulers are daemon threads. When your `main()` method exits, the JVM quits and those daemon threads get stopped.

Place a `Thread.sleep(5000)` at the end of the `main()` method and you'll see the output printed. Alternatively, apply `.toBlocking()` before your `.subscribe()` call.